# How to loop through parent class using __iter__ and yield?

Tags: python, class

I'm having a problem.

I want to loop through a list variable which is set in a parent class. I know that I have to use **iter** and yield but i'm not sure how.

This is what i've got at the moment in the subclass.

```
def __iter__():
        for cell in super()__iter__(cells):
            yield cell
```

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean. Does the parent class have some attribute that is always a list that you want your subclass to iterate over?

Comment: Yes, exactly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understand what you are trying to do correctly, but if you mean you want the child class to iterate over an attribute which is always a list in the parent class you can do that like this:

```
class ParentClass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.list_attribute = [1, 2, 3, 4]


class ChildClass(ParentClass):

    def __iter__(self):
        for item in self.list_attribute:
            yield item
```

And you can use **iter** implicitly like this:

```
child = ChildClass()

for item in child:
    print(item)
```

Comment: Works! Thanks. On my learning site it only showed an example for looping through a class withing the same class not using a Parent Attribute.